# What does '< <' command do in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, operators, command-line-arguments

I can see >> is append and > is overwrite but I do not know what < < does with a space in the middle. What does this do, and does the direction of these arrows matter?

For example:

```
while :; do
mapfile -td '' archives \
< <(find . -type f -name '*.zip' -o -name '*.7z' -print0)

[[ ${#archives[@]} -eq 0 ]] && break
```

Comment: Looks like input/output redirection but it would be only one symbol ' < '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` redirects a file as input to a command.

`<(...)` is a process substitution - it is replaced by a non-seekable file. From that file is read the output of the command inside.